# How do I assign blank space in a div and the button within with the same functionality?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am trying to solve this problem with a program I am writing, I have a div, with the class .main. It occupies a certain amount of space. Within it, there are two buttons. When .button1 is clicked, .light1 is turned on. When .button2 is clicked, .light2 is turned on. BUT. I want it so that when .button1 OR the blank space in .main is clicked, light 1 turns on. So far, when I do that, only the empty space turns .light1 on. Removing .main from the function makes it so .button1 turns .light1 on.

The issue for me is, since the buttons are WITHIN the div, clicking any of buttons activates whatever would activate the div.

I have some working code for this, it is completely self contained, copy paste this into an HTML file if you like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head><meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>I am a test page</title>

    <!--bootstrap 3.3.6 and jquery 2.23-->
    <script src="./js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <style>
        .main
        {
        background-color: rgba(98,159,210, 0.3);
        border-radius: 1px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: black;
        width: 400px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        height: 50px;
        padding:3px;
        cursor: pointer;        
        }


        .button1
        {

        }

        .button2
        {

        }


        .light1
        {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .light2
        {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: red;   

        }
    </style>

</head>


<body>
<div class="container">
    <br><br>
    <div class="main">
         <button class="button1">button1</button>
         <button class="button2">button2</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div class="light1"></div>
    <div class="light2"></div>

</div>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".button1, .main", function()
                   {
                    $(".light1").toggle();

                   });

    $(document).on("click", ".button2", function()
                   {

                    $(".light2").toggle();

                   });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you correctly, following changes should be the answer:

```
$(document).on("click", ".button1, .main", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(".light1").toggle();

});

$(document).on("click", ".button2", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(".light2").toggle();

});
```

Read more about `event.stopPropagation()`

- https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Why both of them? Do I have to add stopPropagation for anything inside the .main class? What is this doing?

Comment: When you click button, the div going to clicked too, so you need to use that to `Prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases (from MDN)`. take a look on that 2 links I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stopPropagation` to prevent the click event of the button1 propagating to the .main click event.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button1, .main", function(e)
                   {
                    e.stopPropagation()
                    $(".light1").toggle();
                    

                   });

    $(document).on("click", ".button2", function(e)
                   {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $(".light2").toggle();

                   });
```

```css
.main
        {
        background-color: rgba(98,159,210, 0.3);
        border-radius: 1px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: black;
        width: 400px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        height: 50px;
        padding:3px;
        cursor: pointer;        
        }


        .button1
        {

        }

        .button2
        {

        }


        .light1
        {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .light2
        {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: red;   

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <br><br>
    <div class="main">
         <button class="button1">button1</button>
         <button class="button2">button2</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div class="light1"></div>
    <div class="light2"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: I am getting this error: jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.