# How can I separate two events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Have a `<div>` Element, which includes a Button.
[image]

Both have Events.
Code for the Button:

```
<button Title="Auswahl anzeigen" class="PopUpButton2" onClick="findArticlesFromSearchBoxButton()">OK</button>');
```

Code for the Div-Element:

```
<div draggable="true" Title="aus aatentechnichen Gr&uuml;nden &#10; k&ouml;nnen beide Suchmethoden &#10; noch nicht miteinander kombiniert werden!" onMouseDown="dragStart(this);" id="divArtikelart">
```

When I click to the button also the clicks on die div-Elements are executed.
How can i avoid this?

Comment: Use `stopPropagation()`. I can't give you an example as you forgot to put the actual useful code in your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I assign blank space in a div and the button within with the same functionality?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030192/how-do-i-assign-blank-space-in-a-div-and-the-button-within-with-the-same-functio)

Comment: Already answered [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030192/how-do-i-assign-blank-space-in-a-div-and-the-button-within-with-the-same-functio/39030455#39030455)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("button").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Add stopPropogation at first line in your button click function. this should resolve issue

Comment: To fit the OP needs, I think it would be better to keep his functions inline and add the event parameter to the functions `onClick="findArticlesFromSearchBoxButton(event)"`